# Adding a swirl to poiseuille flow

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, angular-momentum

I came acroos this question and I have no clue how to answer it:

If we have poiselle flow in a circular pipe of Length $L$ and pressure gradient $\Delta P$ and introduce  a swirl $u_\theta=\omega r$, ie constant rigid body rotation.  A fluid parcel is displaced outwards by $\delta r$.
a) what do the streamlines look like before and after the displacement
b)using conservation of angular momentum show there is a bdoy force and give the direction of the force
How does this increase the flux through the pipe?

---

a)Surely the fluid parcel would undergo simple harmonic motion from its equilibrium poition.

b) $L=(r+\delta r)\times (\omega r)$ taking the time derivative gets:  $0=\dot{\delta r} \times \omega r$ (as it will have the same tangential velocity as it did before).  This means that $\delta r=0$ which is not right.

How do you approach this?  I honestly don't see a way in

Comment: How is this swirl induced?  By rotating the pipe?

Comment: it doesn't say.  it just says a swirl is induced

Comment: Then I guess it is ok to say that the pipe is rotation, and the flow is steady state.